# expose an object directly to browser window, or to a sup property of a global object

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

In my react app, I use webpack to expose my components to the global 'namespace' in order to access them from the browser javascripts and browser console.

For that I use [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader). As I understand, expose-loader is exposing the default export of the module as a named object in the global namespace.

So, if my module `my-module` exposes this object

```
module.exports = {
   Person: Person,
   Company: Company
}
```

Then I can expose the exports using a require similar to this

```
require("expose-loader?MyModuleComponents!my-module");
```

Then, in the browser's console I can see that there exists a property `MyModuleComponents` in the `window` object, and this property holds the exports of my module.

I can, then, reference, for instance, my `Person` component like this

```
var p = MyModuleComponents.Person;
```

Is there a way to

1. Expose each property of the export individually directly into a global object and not as a property of another global object? (for instance, expose my `Person` component in the `window.Person` property and not in the `window.MyModuleComponents.Person` property.
2. Use an object path as the exported object? (for instance exposing my exports in the `MyModule.MyComponents` object in a way similar to this `require("expose-loader?MyModule.MyComponents!my-module");`